# Como dar un salto de linea cuando se llega el final del margen con FPDF

Tags: php, javascript, html, php5, fpdf

Estoy generando un documento PDF con la librería `FPDF` ya lo pude generar, pero la verdad no sé cómo hacer que salte a la siguiente línea cuando llego al final del margen.

El código que tengo me pone los elemento uno al lado del otro con una separación, los primeros tres están bien pero el problema es con el cuarto ya que ese debería bajar a la siguiente línea y así sucesivamente.

**Código PHP**

```
<?php
    include 'fpdf/fpdf.php';
    $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
    $pdf->SetMargins(15,10,15);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf -> Cell(50,10,'sebastian',1,1,'C');
    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY(); 
    $y=$y-10;
    for ($i = 1; $i<=3; $i++){
        $pdf->SetXY($x-150,$y);
        $x = $pdf->GetX();
        $y = $pdf->GetY();
        $pdf -> Cell(50,10,"SEBASTIAN",1,1,'C');
    }
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

**Resultado** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya encontré la solución a mi problema no se si es la mas optima pero así la hice, acepto sugerencias.

```html
<?php
 include 'fpdf/fpdf.php';
 include '../php/conex.php';
 $sql = "SELECT user, centros_salidas.nombre AS centro, territorios.nombre AS territorio, fecha_ini, fecha_fin FROM territorio_predicado, hermanos, centros_salidas, territorios WHERE territorio_predicado.cedula = hermanos.cedula AND territorio_predicado.id_centro = centros_salidas.id_centro AND territorio_predicado.id_territorio = territorios.id_territorio";
 $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
 $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
 $pdf->SetXY(10,10);
 $pdf -> Cell(35,10,'sebastian',1,1,'C');
 $x = 10;
 $y = 10;
 $ap = $pdf->GetPageHeight();
 for ($i = 1; $i<=100; $i++){
  if($x >= 170)
  {
   $y = $y + 15;
   $x = 10;
   $pdf->SetXY($x,$y);
  }else{
   $pdf->SetXY($x+40,$y);
  }
  $x = $pdf->GetX();
  if($y == 295)
  {
   $y = 10;
   $x = 10;
   $pdf->SetXY($x,$y);
   $pdf->AddPage();
  }
  $pdf -> Cell(35,10,"SEBASTIAN",1,1,'C');
 }
 $pdf->Output();
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu código es lo más cercano a aplicar en la solución a mi problema pero lamentablemente no le entiendo al código y así no puedo aplicar